# Element not visible error for button element in Watir

Tags: angularjs, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm using watir to perform automated testing for an application and trying to click on a submit button once I select options for select list and fill up the form.However on clicking the button, it throws element not found error

The html snippet for button tag

```
<button type="submit" class="md-primary md-raised md-button md-default-
theme" ng-transclude=""><span class="ng-binding 
ng-scope">Submit</span><div style="" class="md-ripple-container">
</div>   
</button>
```

The ruby script

```
require "watir"
require "watir-webdriver"
browser =  Watir::Browser.new :firefox
browser.goto 'https://54.69.254.137/webui#/landing'
browser.driver.manage.window.maximize
browser.button(:class =>'sign-in md-button md-default-theme').click
browser.text_field(:id =>'input_001').set('abcadmin@example.com')
browser.text_field(:id =>'input_002').set('password')
browser.button(:class =>'md-primary md-raised md-button md-default-  
theme').click
browser.input(:id =>'input_002').when_present.click
browser.element(aria_label:'What do you want to do?').when_present.click
browser.element(:id =>'select_option_00G').when_present.click
browser.element(aria_label:'About what?').when_present.click
browser.element(:id =>'select_option_00P').when_present.click
browser.textarea(:id =>'input_00N').when_present.set('Discuss about 
javascript and later test the application??')
browser.button(:class =>'md-primary md-raised md-button md-default-   
theme').click
```

It throws the following error

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::ElementNotVisibleError: Element is not 
currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

I tried using

```
browser.button(:class =>'md-primary md-raised md-button md-default-    
theme').when_present.click
```

,but it will throw time out error.Not able to rectify the error .Plz help !!

Comment: The exception says that the element was found but it is not visible. Can you see the element? It might also be possible that you are locating the wrong element. For example, if there are multiple of the submit buttons on the page, the first one is hidden and you are trying to click the second one, this exception will occur.

Comment: The span element is covering/styling the button element. just click on the span instead

Comment: Echoing what @Justin Ko said, the `class` is not guaranteed to be unique. Though I avoid it when I can, this might be a case for locating your element with its XPath. I.e., `browser.button(:xpath => '<xpath here>').click`. That should work without issue (you can pretty easily get the XPath using Chrome Developer Tools. Alternately, if there is only one Submit button, you could try `browser.span(:text, 'Submit').click`.

Comment: Hi !!!!   browser.span(:text, 'Submit').click, worked....Thank you everyone...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select on more than one class at once. To do that you would have to use a css selector instead of a class selector, which would look something like this:

```
browser.button(:css =>'.md-primary.md-raised.md-button.md-default-   
theme').click
```

The class option will only work if you select a single class name, e.g.

```
browser.button(:class =>'md-primary').click
```

Comment: This is not quite true. The `:class` locator does work with multiple classes. However, there is no special logic for handling the classes being in a different order.

Comment: Makes sense, but it makes me wonder what the code in the question isn't working. The classes seem to be in the correct order.

Comment: Based on the error message, the problem is not with finding the button. The problem is with the button not being visible. Given that the class attribute looks general, I would guess that the wrong button is being selected (since Watir uses the first match).

Answer (score 0):

I run into this error quite a bit where I work, when the Front-end devs want to stylize a boring looking element (such as a button or checkbox).

In this particular case the span element is covering/styling the button element. just click on the span instead.

```
browser.span(:text, 'Submit').click
```

Answer (score 0):

Element not visible means that the element was found, but is either hidden or obscured in such a way that a real user would not be able to click the button directly.

Two potential causes for that error, one is that something else covers the element you want.  The other is that there are more than one element that matches in the dom, and the one being selected (unless you give an index value, watir will take the first one it finds) is not visible.

The fast way to determine which is the case is to first get a count of matching elements.. that is easy by inserting a puts into your script right before it tries to click the button  (on two lines for readability)

```
buttons_found = browser.buttons(:class =>'md-primary md-raised md-button md-default-theme').size
puts "I found #{buttons_found} matching buttons"
```

If that returns anything other than 1, then potentially you are selecting a hidden button.  Maybe look instead to select it by having watir look inside a container element, or find a more unique way to identify the button you want.

Note that using class combinations can be a bit brittle since classes are often used to drive CSS formatting.  That can create two problems, one is that any button with the same formatting will likely have the same combination of classes and if the visual design changes the classes can also change    For example if more than one was found, then you could try selecting the button by it's text, such as:

```
browser.button(:text 'Submit').click
```

If there is only a single element found, then look to see if some other element might be masking the one you want, and try clicking on that instead.