# Access a specific dropdown

Tags: html, ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

I am writing Ruby/watir scripts. I've come across a dropdown that appears as italic text that covers up important options. How do I get my scripts to recognize and click this dropdown.  I've tried looking for the specific text and that hasn't worked otherwise I don't see any specific identifying values that I can grab onto.

The HTML of the dropdown inside the div is listed below.

`<span class="help"><a aria-controls="options" aria-expanded="false"  href="#options" data-toggle="collapse" class="collapsed"> Click to view available options. </a></span>`

Comment: the span is 'covering' the dropdown http://stackoverflow.com/a/31587325/3513665

Comment: @Carldmitch Thanks so much this is exactly what I needed to fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below should help:

```
select_list = $browser.select_list(class: 'help')
```

Then if you wanted something like, say the text, you could do:

```
select_list.options(&:text)
```